# Concise way to write a if then else type statement

Tags: c++, c

Let's say I have a criteria and I want to add a delta if that criteria is true, and do the opposite (subtract) if it is false.

```
bool bBoolean;
int iDelta;
int iQuantity;
```

Is there a more concise and elegant way to write that piece of code ? I mean without repeating the keywords iQuantity and iDelta.

```
if(bBoolean)
  iQuantity -= iDelta;
else 
  iQuantity += iDelta;
```

Comment: iQuantity += bBoolean ? -iDelta : iDelta;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shortest thing I can think of is:

```
iQuantity += (bBoolean) ? -iDelta : iDelta;
```

Edit: This is commonly called a ternary statement, though it's proper name (what it's called in the standard) is "conditional expression" or "conditional operator".

(Thanks to Rune for the official name.)

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but the standard uses "conditional expression" / conditional operator.

Comment: I know "ternary statement" from PHP, and now that I think about it, "ternary statement" is a horrible name for it.  Ternary statement could be anything with three operands.  Thanks!

Comment: The best solution seems to be a mix of your solution and Peter's :
`iQuantity += (bBoolean ? -1 : 1)* iDelta;`

It's tricky but as easy to understand as the original if-then-else. But this doesn't apply to the similar problem with `{*,/}` operators.

Answer (score 1):

This is the ternary operator. It is frowned upon by some for its potential to be less clear than `if...else`. I like it, but try to be careful.

```
int sign = criteria ? -1 : 1;
quantity += (delta * sign);
```

Comment: When used appropriately, the conditional operator is significantly clearer than `if...else`.  (In this case, it's hard to say whether its use is appropriate.  It is is, however, I'd go with Corbin's use.)

Answer (score 1):

`iQuantity += (1-2*bBoolean)*iDelta;`

On some processors, the extra arithmetic is faster than branching.

Answer (score -3):

Why not:

```
int tmpDelta = iDelta;
if (iBoolean)
{
  tmpDelta = -tmpDelta;
}
iQuantity += tmpDelta;
```

To me, when I write or read code, I prefer to have something that as straight-forward as possible. This says that the code will always update `iQuantity`, and that the update will be inversed if `iBoolean` is true.

Edit: Updated not to modify `iDelta`.

Comment: Maybe they don't want the value of `iDelta` to be changed.

Comment: this is a horrible way to write your code. on any subsequent entry to this code you will have ***no*** idea what's the current `iDelta`'s sign is. ***NO*** idea. -1. This is also wrong: the original intent was to subtract when `iBoolean` is true but you flip the sign - one time subtracting, and another time *adding* the delta.

Comment: @WillNess. 1) This code assumes that `iDelta` is a local variable. I've updated the answer to reflect this. 2) Is it correct. If the condition is false the value is simply added. If it is true, `iDelta` is negated before added to `iQuantity`, *this is the same as subtraction* -- simple school math...